# Possible to integrate FrontPage as landing page?

Tags: sharepoint-online, design

I am maintaining a project in SharePoint using SharePoint Online.

As there are not many choices for e.g. table formatting (all very inflexible and ugly), I was wondering whether it is possible to create a webpage in **FrontPage** and integrate it as a landing page in SharePoint?

Are there any alternatives to make the SharePoint look nicer? With the current choice I am a bit stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Is FrontPage not discontinued? I'm assuming you can extract the html from it?

You can create an html page and upload it to your Site Assets through SharePoint designer. Likewise, you can add other javascript libraries and css files into the Site Assets folder and reference them. E.g. You could use Bootstrap (although it's probably not the best example as it needs tailored)

Once you have your page designed and uploaded, any script and style files linked (make sure they are all checked in) you can add a Content Editor Web Part to your homepage. 
In the webpart settings the top option is "Content Link", add the link to your html file to the webpart and save. That should solve the issue.

Alternatively, you could code it within the page using the Script Editor Web Part (although I'd recommend the first method)